# errno failure with rename RTEMS

Tags: c++, rtems

I am using the ***[rename](https://docs.rtems.org/releases/rtemsdocs-4.9.2/share/rtems/html/posix_users/posix_users00105.html)*** function with `RTEMS` to attempt to rename files. I am setting up a correct error handling and reporting system when i discovered that `RTEMS` does not seem to be conforming to its own *errno* reporting guide.

So the function in failure will always return -1. The current example is in a directory `</D\>` where i have the following:

```
 </D\LALALA>
 </D\LALALA_2>
 </D\OTHER_DIRECTORY>
```

I call `rename("LALALA_1", "LALALA_2")` which works correctly and the folder is renamed. So i know the function works. If i call `rename("LALALA", "LALALA_2")`, it fails returning -1... which is great, but instead of `EEXIST` i get `errno == -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this looks to be a bug with the `RTEMS` implementation.

https://lists.rtems.org/pipermail/bugs/2014-January/004755.html

It is not likely that it will ever be fixed.